# Grails: trouble with AddTo

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I was trying to prove to myself that addTo will save both the added domain object as well as its parent with a save on the parent.  I constructed this simple test:

```
package testapp

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(Person)
class PersonSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }


    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test PersonCreation"() {
        when: "create a person with a hobby"
        Hobby h = new Hobby(name: "Fishing")
        Person p = new Person()
        p.first="Sam"
        p.last="Parker"
        p.age = 30
        p.addToHobby(h)
        p.save()
        then: "Hobby is saved as well"
        Hobby.count() == 1
    }
}
```

Running it, however, produced this error at the `p.addToHobby(h)`
line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.addTo(GormEntity.groovy:350)
    at testapp.PersonSpec.test PersonCreation(PersonSpec.groovy:27)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

The domain classes are as simple as you might expect:

Person:

```
package testapp

class Person {

  String first
  String last
  Integer age

  static hasMany = [hobby: Hobby]

  static constraints = {}
}
```

Hobby:

```
class Hobby {
    String name
    static constraints = {}
    static belongsTo = [person: Person]

}
```

I've tried cleaning and recompiling, no change.  (Grails version 3.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the @Mock annotation for Person and Hobby. That will add the dynamic methods (like addTo) to the domain-classes.

```
@Mock([Person, Hobby])
class PersonSpec extends Specification {
    ...your test code...
}
```